# How to bind values in table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I try to bind the value in table in asp using jQuery. But the value is not showing??
It showing"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "XXXX.aspx/XXXX",
    method: "post",
    datatype: "json",

    success: function(data) {
      var _table = $("#table1 tbody ");

      _table.empty();
      $(data).each(function(index, row) {

        _table.append('<tr><td>' + row.Id + '</td><td>' + row.Date + '</td><td>' + row.Shift + '</td><td>' + row.Region + '</td><td>' + row.Time + '</td><td>' + row.Name + '</td></tr>')

      });

    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: your problem is in Server. fix it then maybe your data will show

Comment: 500 error related to unhandled exception. Can you show the method and line of server-side code that produces the error (use debugger)?

Comment: Still it is not binding data guradio

Comment: A 500 Error is a general error thrown by the IIS Server simply indicating it encountered an error. You will need to review your IIS logs or increase reporting to identify why the aspx is generating the 500 Error. I see you are Posting to the aspx without any `data`, so maybe it is expecting some type of data passed to it?